# In PowerShell, how to use a SQL column value in an if statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to use a PowerShell script to send email notices based on the number of days returned by a DATEDIFF.

The script works and sends the correct information.  With "top 5" in the SELECT statement I get the first 5 matching records.

BusinessDays is the value I'm interested in.  top 5 returns three records with positive values and two with negative values (because they are not late yet). The values are good.

I want to return only the records with positive values, or only the ones with negative values.

I tried using a foreach ($row in $data), but that just gave me 5 messages for each value.
Obviously, I don't know PowerShell.

How would I fix it to send either the 3 positive values for BusinessDays or the 2 negative values?

```
<# connection string and SQL command to execute #>
[String] $now = Get-Date
[String] $constr = 'Server=MySQLServer; Database=PolicyTracker; Integrated Security=SSPI;'
[String] $sqlCmd = @'
SELECT top 5 PolicyID, PolicyNumber, PolicyName, AnticipatedDueDate, DaysLate, Lead, Department, AssignedDate, OnHold, Status, 'david@Company.com' AS David
  ,(DATEDIFF(dd, AnticipatedDueDate, getdate()))
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, AnticipatedDueDate, getdate()) * 2)
  +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, AnticipatedDueDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'BusinessDays'

    FROM Policies
    WHERE 
   ((DATEDIFF(dd, AnticipatedDueDate, getdate()))
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, AnticipatedDueDate, getdate()) * 2)
  +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, AnticipatedDueDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) % 5 = 0
'@


$set = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
(New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($sqlCmd, $constr)).Fill($set) | out-null

$data = $set.tables[0]  <# This was not part of the original script, but I put $data in the if() below.  I just had if(1 -eq 1) before.  As it is, -gt 0 sends 5 of one message and -lt 0 sends 5 of the other.  I need either the 3 positive values or the 2 negative ones, not all of them. #>

$set.Tables[0] |
  % {
    $to = $_.David | ? { $_ -ne '' -and !($_ -is [DBNull]) }
    <# Mail parameters #>
if($data.Rows[0].BusinessDays -gt 0) {
    Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -Body "<div style='border: 3px double black; padding:20px; margin:20px;'><span style='font-size:24px;'>This policy/procedure is overdue for updating. Please provide a status update and a new anticipated completion date.  Thank you.<br /><br />Lead: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.Lead)</span><br /><br />Policy Number: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.PolicyNumber)</span><br /><br />Policy Name: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.PolicyName)</span><br /><br />Anticipated Due Date: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.AnticipatedDueDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))</span><br /><br />            Days Late: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.BusinessDays)</span><br /><br />Status: <br /><span style='color:blue;'>$($_.Status)</span></div>" -SmtpServer mail.careersourcebroward.com -From "Policy and Procedure Tracker <csbd@careersourcebroward.com>" -To $to -Cc DMegnin@CareerSourceBroward.com -Subject "This policy/procedure is overdue or updating.  Please provide a status update and a new anticipated completion date.  Thank you."
}
else 
{
 <# foreach ($row in $data) #>

    Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -Body "<div style='border: 3px double black; padding:20px; margin:20px;'><span style='font-size:24px;'>This policy/procedure is <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.BusinessDays)</span> days overdue for updating. Please provide a status update and a new anticipated completion date.  Thank you.<br /><br />Lead: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.Lead)</span><br /><br />Policy ID: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.PolicyID)</span><br /><br />Policy Name: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.PolicyName)</span><br /><br />Anticipated Due Date: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.AnticipatedDueDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))</span><br /><br />Days Late: <span style='color:blue;'>$($_.BusinessDays)</span><br /><br />Status: <br /><span style='color:blue;'>$($_.Status)</span></div>" -SmtpServer mail.careersourcebroward.com -From "Policy and Procedure Tracker <csbd@careersourcebroward.com>" -To $to -Cc DMegnin@CareerSourceBroward.com -Subject "This policy/procedure is overdue or updating.  Please provide a status update and a new anticipated completion date.  Thank you."
}
  }
```

Comment: One of the messages will be for the positive values of BusinessDays, the other message will be for the negative values.  i.e. going to be due in n days and overdue by n days.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but you can split your rows into two collections based on whether their `.BusinessDays` column value is positive or not as follows: `$positiveRows, $zeroOrNegativeRows = $data.Rows.Where({ $_.BusinessDays -gt 0 }, 'Split' })`

Comment: Thank you.  I think this will help me.  It's the "if" statement that I'm having trouble with.  That and I don't know PowerShell well, at all.  ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the "as follows:"  I tried putting that as the if condition, but that gave me a "Missing closing ')' in method call. Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement."  I also don't understand 'split.'
I really don't know PowerShell, but I have to schedule these email reminders to send one message before the due date and the different message body if the due date is passed.

Comment: I think I've fixed the issue where the if statement wasn't switching between the first and second message body depending of if the .BusinessDays was positive or negative.  I only needed if($_.BusinessDays -lt 0) instead of all the $data.Rows[0] stuff.  I'm still working on getting every fifth one with the % 5 = 0 Modulus thing in the SELECT statement.  It may actually be working as it.  I'm just starting to test that.